# Inconsistent search results from elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have an index consisting of roughly 40.000 vessel names

When posting a query for vessel name i.e. "TUC" I get a number of results
When reducing the query term to "T" however, the results I got from the "TUC" query is not in the result set?

I'm a bit lost of what's causing this, but wondering if it is being cut out because the total result set is too large?

Some stats:

Query:

```
{
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [
            {
                "query_string" : {
                    "fields" : ["vesselName"],
                    "type" : "phrase_prefix",
                    "query" : "T"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Result (first):

```
"max_score": 12.450134,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "vesselsindex",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "06ad4663-42f6-4771-b350-0d3b7a1b3229",
            "_score": 12.450134,
            "_source": {
                "vesselId": "06ad4663-42f6-4771-b350-0d3b7a1b3229",
                "callSign": "FATA",
                "vesselName": "TAAPE"
            }
        },
```

Result (When using searh term "TUC"):

```
{
            "_index": "vesselsindex",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "e7bea95c-6819-48b1-b52e-0a8fbaeef1df",
            "_score": 11.831188,
            "_source": {
                "vesselId": "e7bea95c-6819-48b1-b52e-0a8fbaeef1df",
                "callSign": "PBAQ",
                "vesselName": "TUCANA"
            }
        },
```

Settings:

```
{
"vesselsindex": {
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "provided_name": "vesselsindex",
            "max_result_window": "50000",
            "creation_date": "1604061335143",
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "keywordWithCaseIgnore": {
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                        ],
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "M-m3nIB5TqeiPNR2NR5zWQ",
            "version": {
                "created": "7060099"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stats:

```
{
"_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
},
"_all": {
    "primaries": {
        "docs": {
            "count": 43510,
            "deleted": 0
        },
        "store": {
            "size_in_bytes": 12762612
        },
```

Comment: Did you tried this  {
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "message": {
        "query": "T"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: No luck. That returend no hits
{
    "took": 21,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}

Comment: @lewi did you get a chance to go through answer ??

Comment: Yes, tried it now, Stackoverflow was temporarily blocked by company proxy

Comment: @lewi stackoverflow is being blocked, thats a crime for s/w company :D

Comment: Yes, I knkow. We were in the middle of a network migration process, so they are (partly) excused :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as ES by default returns only the 10 top search results, and when you are searching for `T` that time top 10 documents might be the ones which is present in the `TUC` query search results.

If you want to get more search results, increase the [size param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html), which is costly hence used mainly for pagination to improve the performance of your search queries.

**You can provide the size param as query param or as part of your search request body.**

You can try _search?size=44000 in your search request URL and it should return you all the search results

Comment: Same result. Using _search?size=10000 gives a result with total hits = 873. My service is deleting and recreating the index on each restart, and I see that total hits value differ between each restart.

Comment: @lewi why your service is deleting and recreating the indices ??  also before this what was the total hits??

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately no effect. I am putting the issue aside for awhile to focus on other stuff. Thanks for the inputs though